# Why have those comments been deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-comments

Why have the comments been deleted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/10007362/140719?

Really, what is it with the mods and deletions?? Those comments explained to the asker (and to other newbies) ***why this question was closed***. Don't you feel it's stupid to delete them? How is anyone (but us old farts) looking at the question now to know why it was closed?

Comment: Probably the comments have been flagged. What is the point of explaining why the question was closed, when it is reported in the "closed as…" block?

Comment: @Kiamlaluno what is the harm of explain exactly why a question was closed?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Because close reasons are generic (*especially* "too localized"), and comment might be specific?

Comment: @thecoshman It depends from the number of comments; if there is an exchange of 5-6 comments between somebody that is saying the question is too localized, and the OP who is saying that is not true, or that the OP needs to know the answer, then I guess it could be deleted. There is a reason for flagging that says "obsolete."

Comment: Do you have the deleted comments? I guess it turned into "comments war" between some users so moderator decided to clean it all. (After enough flags were received, probably)

Comment: @CatPlusPlus They are generic, but they explain why the question was closed; in the case of a too localized question, the key point is, "This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors."

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: No comment wars. Oli gave several reasons why he voted to close, the OP asked, Oli explained more. Oli's comments had several upvotes because they explained it well. My comment was deleted, too, but since I had it linked in a chatroom, I just added it back.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: The comments explained why the SO community thinks those questions are unlikely to be helpful to future visitors. There were several of them, because the OP kept asking, ___because he didn't understand this___.

Comment: @sbi There is not need to explain it. If the OP wants to know for which exactly reason the question was considered too localized, he can ask on this very site.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: The OP _asked_ even after Oli had explained it at the very question. So there _is_ need of explanation, and he asked at the perfect place.

Comment: @sbi Where do you read that such explanation _must_ be given in the comments for the question? Comments are second-class citizens, and they are removed when they are not (anymore) relevant. A comment saying, e.g., that the approach described in the question is not much appropriate makes more sense than a comment saying why a user thinks the question is too localized, IMO.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I already said that I read the necessity of such an explanation in the user _asking_ for it. What more necessity do you need? Whether you consider comments 1st, 2nd, 3rd, or whatever class citizens I don't care. Comments are often immensely helpful for clarifying points, getting to a conclusion, reaching a consensus, explaining a decision, and for many other things. Sometimes they aren't necessary anymore after a conclusion has been reached (I then usually flag them as obsolete), and sometimes they should stay around, lest future visitors repeat the very same discussion.

Comment: Think of Stack Overflow as a forest full with trees. Each question is a tree, each answer is a branch and each comment is a leaf. Tree got plenty of leaves and they're rather insignificant in general. When the forest ranger spot a tree with rotten leaf - even one - he will casually clean the whole branch.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: Think of me as the ranger questioning that practice.

Comment: @sbi so you should have a chat with the forest owner about policy change - but honestly can't see such thing happening.

Comment: @sbi The fact the OP is asking doesn't mean you need to answer in comments. The answer could have been "ask on MSO." Even questions and answers are deleted; why would you think that comments, which are considered second-class citizen, should always be kept? As a matter of fact, you can flag a comment for being obsolete, while you cannot do the same for a post. Stack Exchange always taught that you should not write something important in a comment, because a comment could be removed any time.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: Nor can I. So why would I care wasting my time? It's bad enough to get snide and unfriendly answers from his minions every time I am asking something. Judging from their behavior, that boss guy must be a real badass. Thanks, but I'd rather take MBs of template errors any day.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I would now have to answer to you what I have already said. Since you dismiss it without taking the time to address it, we'd be running in circle forever. HAND.

Comment: @sbi indeed, one possible conclusion is to not try and explain why question got closed as it might be waste of time.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: How in the world can you conclude this from what I said?!

Comment: @sbi from "why would I care wasting my time" - so what did you mean?

Comment: @sbi The fact comments can be deleted at any time is well known; it's not something that suddenly started to happen. [Jeff Atwood also wrote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39288/remove-moderator-abilities-to-delete-comments#comment86815_39296), "@shog9 not every user-generated byte committed to memory is sacred. Particularly in comments, which are meant to be lightweight and ephemeral. If you want to post content more likely to survive, do it in an answer."

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I would now have to answer to you what I have already said. Since you dismiss it without taking the time to address it, we'd be running in circle forever. HAND.

Comment: @sbi http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128090/why-have-those-comments-been-deleted#comment349356_128090

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: You: "Chat with the forest owner about policy change." Me: "That'd be a waste of time." It's the forest owner, the meta crowd, not some innocent passers-by asking a stupid question, who is a waste of time to discuss with. (And let me add that "forest owner" seems to perfectly match the attitude towards SO that the common meta regular radiates.)

Answer (score 9):

**If only** there was one question... one question out of ***three million***, that had a long comment thread which covered the reason why that particular question was closed...

It might be **the one**--the one comment thread that helps new users *just get it*.  All we have to do is point people to that one question and they'll understand *everything*.

Why not?  We already cover this

- In the post notice underneath the question
- In the faq
- In meta
- In thousands of other questions where users have left comments detailing why a particular question sucked

But, who knows?  Maybe *this is the one that would have worked*.

Or, it might have been redundant noise that was drawing offensive flags.

If you want, I can post the text of your comment so that you can copypaste it in all the closed C++ questions.  Just give me the heads up.

Comment: Your answer explains why you don't think the comments are worth reviving. I was, however, asking why they were deleted. This your answer doesn't explain.

Comment: @sbi: comments flagged as offensive.  Question closed.  A mod could read the comments, try to determine which are relevant and which are not, then prune out the worthless ones and then edit anything that is offensive out of the ones that are left... or just purge comments because the question is closed and move on to other flags.

Comment: What was offensive about Oli's comments explaining why the question was deemed too localized? That's nonsense.

Comment: @sbi: Hey! Welcome to moderation!  Here's your cup of coffee.  If people in general were rational, we wouldn't have to deal with most flags. Unfortunately, half of people think stuff that's not offensive actually is, the other half think that stuff that's deleted shouldn't be.  And we're stuck in the middle, catching crap from both sides!  Yay!

Comment: I don't drink coffee and I know of the basics of moderation and its quirks (I'm not exactly a newbie), but thanks all the same. So if I interpret right what I read, you are saying the moderator might have messed up in deleting Oli's comments? If so — why don't you simply write that as an answer? That would be a sufficient information for me to accept an answer.

Comment: @sbi: Eh.  I'd rather go about it in a roundabout way.

Comment: @sbi I guess Won't is saying that, whatever moderators do, there will always be somebody who is not unhappy with what done from moderators. I don't read what Won't said as, "the moderator might have messed up."

Comment: +1, agreed with what you say and @sbi the way I understand it he says "Moderators are flooded with flags and on certain cases prefer to wipe it all out when it doesn't really matter anyway to save some precious time"

Comment: @Won't: No it isn't roundabout. It's condescending, snide, and annoyed. And I guess it's the usual meta crowd which comes by and upvotes such an "answer", despite the fact that it doesn't even bother to answer the question, not even after it had been pointed out that it fails to.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Won't gave no rational reason for deleting those comments, and, as I read it, even said there might not be one. I am sorry, but I can't help but consider irrational deletions as "messing things up".

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: As I said, if this was an answer, I'd accept that. However, Won't's "answer" fails to even address my question.

Comment: @sbi: Why, the answer was provided in the comments.  Are you telling me that isn't acceptable?  Ironic.

Comment: @sbi what about "Those comments were deleted because many people flagged one or more comments on that question as offensive"?

Comment: Will - it will be awesomelly ironic if you will now delete all comments here. ;)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: And what about "What was offensive about Oli's comments explaining why the question was deemed too localized?"

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: I'm actually planning on that.  It will be so ironic that it will be goldic.

Comment: @Won't: Do you _really_ want me to tell _you_ that I cannot accept a comment as an answer?? Isn't this just another snide remark, aimed at getting cheers from your peers, rather than trying to resolve this issue?

Comment: @sbi good chance that nothing was offensive about that specific comment, it was innocent victim of global comment wipeout. I agree with the wipeout and understand the reason behind it that's all.

Comment: You guys sit on quite high horses, looking down your noses at the rest of the crowd that dares to come by and ask one of those questions already answered or — gasp! — even dares to disagree with you, elbowing each other about the funny comments you give to those dummies — and then you wonder people call you the meta police. How pathetic.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: And I now understand that it was an innocent victim. And while I do not even begrudge the mod doing it, I wanted to understand why it was done, and if it was done without reason, I want to log my disagreement with this case in particular, and the practice in general. Yes, I knew it would end badly (and you guys never fail to meet those expectations), yet I couldn't help but had to point out what I thought is wrong.

Comment: @sbi so to sum things up, you are against global wipeout of comments, no matter the reason?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: No. As I said, I flag comments threads as obsolete more often than I disagree with others getting deleted. But I only do this when I think the comments will more confuse, rather than help, future visitors. And if in doubt, I'd rather let them live. In a few month's time they'll be collapsed by default anyway. I have seen mods wiping out discussions (about technical aspects of an answer) _in progress_, comments where others clarified an abandoned answer, where someone (on meta) disagreed with certain people, and other atrocities. With those I disagree.

Comment: @sbi: I actually think this is incredibly trivial, which shows itself in the tone of my answer and comments.  In addition, its been official policy that comments are not considered content, and therefore important information shouldn't be placed in them.  I know that won't satisfy you in the least, but that's where it stands currently.  One could say that it is pathetic that this fact causes you such incredible angst, but that would be rude of anyone to say.  Please flag such comments as offensive.

Comment: @Won't: "I actually think this is incredibly trivial, which shows itself in the tone of my answer and comments." Yeah, right. Never let any facts stand in the way of your prejudices. And never let any opportunity pass by unused to make fun of, or just plainly insult, a dissenter. I am so sorry for you.

Comment: @Won't: By countering my criticism that you have nothing to offer but snide remarks with a snide remark, you feel like you have won a rhetoric victory, don't you? And your peer hail you for it. My tone isn't condescending, BTW, it's sad.